# Setting paths for different types

Tags: graphics, paths

I wonder if it is possible to set several paths for different types of images, that im including in my document. Currently im using

```
\graphicspath{{./Figures/}}
```

for saying that, it should use figures folder for includes. But now i have diagrams that are saved as pdf and they are in `./diagrams`. Is there any posibility to define several paths as variables that i can use them later?

Comment: You can include multiple paths in the `\graphicspath` argument. All should be enclosed in brackets and end with a \. In your case `\graphicspath{{./Figures/}{./diagrams/}}`. But I am not quite sure what you mean with saving them as variables to use them later.